# How to convert the outcome from np.mean to csv?

Tags: pandas, csv, image-processing

so I wrote a script to get the average grey value of each image in a folder. when I execute print(np.mean(img) I get all the values on the terminal. But i don't know how to get the values to a csv data.

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd


files = glob.glob("/media/rene/Windows8_OS/PROMON/Recorded Sequences/6gParticles/650rpm/*.png")
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    finalArray = np.mean(img)
    print(finalArray)
```

so far it works but I need to have the values in a csv data. I tried csvwriter and pandas but did not mangage to get a file containing the grey scale values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
files = glob.glob("/media/rene/Windows8_OS/PROMON/Recorded Sequences/6gParticles/650rpm/*.png")
mean_lst = []
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    mean_lst.append(np.mean(img))

pd.DataFrame({"mean": mean_lst}).to_csv("path/to/file.csv", index=False)
```